# React Native Search bar position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

New to RN. I am displaying a Google map and a search bar. 
Problem is that the search bar is under the status bar.

How can I adjust this to be below the status bar at least?

```
<View>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
        <SearchBar
          ref='searchBar'
          placeholder='Find me'
          barStyle="black"
          showsCancelButtonWhileEditing={false}
        />
        <MapView
          provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
          style={ styles.container }
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 32.815013,
            longitude: -117.273404,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If this issue replicates only in iOS you could check the platform to apply the correct styling.

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
    <SearchBar
      ref='searchBar'
      placeholder='Find me'
      barStyle="black"
      showsCancelButtonWhileEditing={false}
    />
    <MapView
      provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
      style={ styles.container }
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 32.815013,
        longitude: -117.273404,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle: {
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'iOS' ? 20 : 10
    }
})
```

Comment: It's not picking up `Platform.OS === 'iOS' ` in the iP simulator? Always the `false` part

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview.html)

Just wrap your entire view with SafeAreaView.It automatically adds space on IOS devices.

```
<SafeAreView style={{flex:1}}>
<View>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
        <SearchBar
          ref='searchBar'
          placeholder='Find me'
          barStyle="black"
          showsCancelButtonWhileEditing={false}
        />
        <MapView
          provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
          style={ styles.container }
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 32.815013,
            longitude: -117.273404,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```